# How to adjust Height and width in android stagefright Media Player

Tags: android, c++, stagefright

Is there any way to adjust height and width of a Video in file which is similar to SoftAVC.Cpp..

In my code the width and height is fixed(i.e 832*480) for particular video.But I want to play different video's What should I do?, so that I can play different Video's.

My Code

```
IntdecHEVC::IntdecHEVC(
                           const char *name,
                           const OMX_CALLBACKTYPE *callbacks,
                           OMX_PTR appData,
                           OMX_COMPONENTTYPE **component)
    : SoftVideoDecoderOMXComponent(name, componentName, codingType,
                                   kProfileLevels, ARRAY_SIZE(kProfileLevels),

                                   832 /* width */, 480 /* height */, callbacks,
                                   appData, component),
    mFlushOutBuffer(NULL),
    mOmxColorFormat(OMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar),
    mChangingResolution(false),
    mSignalledError(false),
    mIsInFlush(false),
    mReceivedEOS(false),


    mStride(mWidth) {
        const size_t kMinCompressionRatio = 4 /* compressionRatio (for Level 4+) */;
        const size_t kMaxOutputBufferSize = 2048 * 2048 * 3 / 2;

        m_lOriginalWidthY = 832;
        m_lHeightY = 480;
        m_lOriginalWidthUV = m_lOriginalWidthY/2;
        m_lHeightUV = m_lHeightY/2;


        // INPUT_BUF_SIZE is given by HEVC codec as minimum input size   changed by pooja 11-4
        initPorts(
                  kNumInputBuffers,INPUT_BUF_SIZE, kNumOutputBuffers, CODEC_MIME_TYPE);
    }
```

Comment: is this c++ question or android?

Comment: Native Code (C++)  of android Stagefright Media Player

Comment: okay, so what is the problem? Can not understand properly.

Comment: I am not able to play videos with different resolution..I was playing only one video i.e Party Scene With the resolution 832*480(Mention in above code)..but i want to play videos with different resolution...so can you help me with this???

Comment: In your code, there is a hardcoding of `m_lOriginalWidthY = 832;         m_lHeightY = 480;`Shouldn't these be read from the bitstream instead of hardcoding?

Comment: Yes I want to read it from bitstream only..But when first access unit comes which contains SPS(pic info height and width)  ,that time onqueuefilled gets called..But actual height and width settings are in Constructor...   so before onqueuefilled call , constructor sets height and width....Is it possible to set height and width at some different location i.e after reading it from 1st Access Unit????

Comment: In any decoder, when you initially create it, you will get the `width` and `height` coming from the file container. However, when a stream comes in with a `SPS` and `PPS` whose dimensions are different, the codec should raise a resolution changed i.e. `OMX_EventPortSettingsChanged` as here: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#6370 . In the implementation of `allocateBuffers` i.e. when port is re-enabled and allocate is called, codec should reset the context to match the new resolution. Hope this helps !!